# Which is healthier: Mayo, Honey Mustard or Oil + Vinegar?

Tags: calories, food

Which is healthier on a sub sandwich? Mayo, Honey Mustard or Oil + Vinegar?

Comment: Nutrition questions unrelated to exercise are off-topic according to the [faq].

Comment: Which stack exchange site deals with general nutrition questions?

Comment: At the current moment, there isn't one. There is a [Health proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6160/health) that you might want to consider. I can't say for certainty whether your question will be on-topic there or when it will launch into beta, but you can certainly explore that avenue.